# Trying to move model code to shared concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model with the following two methods which are required in another model so I thought I'd try sharing them via a concern instead of duplicating the code.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base

  def ancestors
    Region.where("lft < ? AND ? < rgt", lft, rgt)
  end

  def parent
    self.ancestors.order("lft").last
  end

end
```

I have created a file in app/models/concerns/sets.rb and my new model reads:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sets
end
```

sets.rb is:

```
module Sets
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def ancestors
    Region.where("lft < ? AND ? < rgt", lft, rgt)
  end

  def parent
    self.ancestors.order("lft").last
  end

  module ClassMethods

  end
end
```

Question:
How do I share a method between models when the method references the model such as "Region.where..."

Answer (score 2):

Either by referencing the class of the including model (but you need to wrap the instance methods in an `included` block):

```
included do
  def ancestors
    self.class.where(...) # "self" refers to the including instance
  end
end
```

or (better IMO) by just declaring the method as a class method, in which case you can leave the class itself out altogether:

```
module ClassMethods
  def ancestors
    where(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: In the second method how do I reference the variables lft & rgt as they relate to the instance itself?

Comment: You're right, I don't think you can. So in this case don't use the class method approach; if you don't need to use instance variables for the query, use the class method approach. The advantage is that they're chainable, e.g. `Region.ancestors.limit(10)`.